# Common background image for header and search of SectionList on React-Native app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I'm working on a requirement where I have to add a background image(i.e., replace the complete navy blue area in the below image) for the section which contains both React-Native navigation header and searchbar of sectionlist.

The challenging part here is that both are different components

[image]

Comment: try to give backgroundColor as navy blue for both header & seachbar component.

Comment: @SDushan - That's my screen, I want it to be replaced by an Image

Comment: Oops sorry. if you can share your code then someone might be able to help you.